# how to convert the player current time to seconds

Tags: macos

i want to convert AVPlayer current to minutes and seconds.
Please suggest me how to convert Player  Current time  to minutes and seconds
when i  gone through the documentation of avplayer,i came to know that it returns cmtime

Answer (score 0):

Check Apple's documentation for CMTime: [CMTime Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreMedia/Reference/CMTime/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CMTime).

`value` divided by `timescale` equals seconds.